# Acrobat and/or Reader Error ".tmp" when using fdf

Tags: php, pdf, internet-explorer, fdf

I'm populating PDF's via FDF (& php) and for the most part it works fine however some users are getting either a "Acrobat cannot open "Acrxyz.tmp" (or a "Reader cannot open "xyz.tmp", in some cases).

I've found info about possible causes surrounding: apache "MOD-Deflate", IE Cache and Volatile memory & "fdf_close" among other things..

some config info: it's on apache 2 with (the Mod_deflate module), I don't have fdftk installed so can't do much about fdf_close. the fdf is called with an include. and these are all through https SSL

Users are on IE anywhere from IE 6 to IE 8 most using acrobat 8 or Reader 8.x or 9.2

most users get the pdf without a problem but.... any suggestions to help narrow my search to server setting user-config etc. or solutions would be helpful?

here's the header info if that helps
    // Header is required for explorer to send this file to Acrobat Viewer
    header ("Content-Type: application/vnd.fdf");
    // Prevent caching
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: public");

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the End-all or complete answer but just updating (and I'm sure the solution doesn't come without rasing other issues)

One of the major culprits was a machine with IE 6 on it.

in an effort to trouble-shoot I went down the Mod_Deflate route

changed :

```
# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Removed the !'s to reverse the !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html and (after a restart) that machine with IE 6 no longer gets those errors.

I'm also going to want to target that just to the MSIE 6 browser.

As I said I'm sure there are good reasons not to do that of at all possible and the wheels could come off tomorrow but I'll see what happens.